# How to save a tabbed json file

Tags: python, json

I have a function:

```
def save(path,data):
    file = open(path,'w',encoding='utf-8')
    file.write(json.dumps(data))
    file.close()
```

It saves the file, but without tabbing. Everything goes in one line.

```
save('1.json',{"1":"222"})
```

How do I make it save in tab format?

```
{
  "1":"222"
}
```

Comment: `json.dumps(data, indent=2)` will indent with two spaces. Tabs are not recommend since they are subject of interpretation.

Answer (score 1):

Use `indent` argument with `json.dumps` as below:

```
import json

def save(path, data):    
    file = open(path,'w',encoding='utf-8')
    file.write(json.dumps(data, indent=4))
    file.close()
    
save('1.json',{"1":"222"})
```

Comment: What if I want to use tab instead of spaces?

Comment: As another user pointed,  tabs are not recommend since they are subject of interpretation.

Answer (score 1):

`json.dumps` have an indent keyword argument to specify the indentation of the output.

```py
def save(path, data, indent=2):
    file = open(path,'w',encoding='utf-8')
    file.write(json.dumps(data, indent=indent))
    file.close()
save('1.json',{"1":"222"})
```

1.json

```json
{
  "1": "222"
}
```

Comment: What if I want to use tab instead of spaces?

Comment: @ЛёняДекарт I'm not sure if that's a viable option. However, what you could do is use four spaces for indent and manually replace them with tabs(`'\t'`).

Answer (score 1):

use params `indent`

```
def save(path,data):
    with open(path,'w',encoding='utf-8') as f:
        f.write(json.dumps(data,indent=4))
```